# best ssh program for Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, cygwin, kde

I know of Putty.  I currently use rxvt (via Cygwin).

Is there a more "integrated" terminal program for Windows out there?
e.g. something closer to KDE's kconsole -- where I can have multiple shells all tabbed within the same window.  etc.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, Cygwin's rxvt isn't an ssh client. Cygwin's ssh client is OpenSSH, from the OpenBSD project.

Comment: not pedantic at all, i welcome the correction, thanks.

Comment: +1 for the pedantic comment :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So far as I know, Putty is the best open-source non-commercial SSH client for Windows. For tabbed sessions there is http://puttycm.free.fr/cms/

You could also look at commercial programs such as Reflection for Unix and SecureCRT. (Edit:) They both offer tabbed sessions.

Another option might be Putty + screen (`man screen`)?

---

(Edit:)

#### Summary of programs suggested in this & other answers and comments

In no particular order.

- [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/) <sub>*RGB*</sub>
- Putty + [PuttyCM](http://puttycm.free.fr/cms/) <sub>*RGB*</sub>
- Putty + [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) <sub>*RGB*</sub>
- [Reflection](http://www.attachmate.com/Products/Terminal+Emulation/Reflection/ruo/) <sub>*RGB*</sub> - $120
- [SecureCRT](http://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/) <sub>*RGB*</sub> - $99
- [Anzio Lite](http://www.anzio.com/product/anzio-lite) <sub>*RGB*</sub> - $40
- [mRemote](http://www.mremote.org/) <sub>*gWaldo*</sub>
- [mRemoteNG](http://www.mremoteng.org/) <sub>*Mircea Vutcovici*</sub>
- [Kitty](http://www.9bis.net/kitty) - a Putty fork <sub>*UniDyne*</sub>
- [Poderosa](http://en.poderosa.org/) <sub>*Cypher*</sub>
- ssh from [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) OpenSSH] <sub>*Steven Monai*</sub>
- [Absolute Telnet](http://www.celestialsoftware.net/) <sub>*Adrien*</sub>
- [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) <sub>*miguelo*</sub>

<sub>Prices for commercial products are indicative only, check before choosing</sub>

*I thought it would be useful to have a concise list. For votes, see also below.*

Comment: +1 for Putty+screen.  Screen has the nice side effect that if you ssh connection get terminated, your processes do not.

Comment: mRemote (and mRemoteNG) allow for multiple sessions in separate tabs in the same window.

Comment: another +1 for screen.

Comment: tmux is a nice alternative to screen as well. Among other things, it supports shared sessions without needing super user privileges for configuration.

Comment: Reflection is a hellish piece of software. I worked Help Desk at a big corporate investment banking firm and it refused to install from the .msi package if the user wasn't local administrator. I did not have access to the gpo that was pushing it.

Answer (score 4):

kiTTY is an up-to-date port of the venerable old puTTY. It supports tabbed sessions and a bunch of other niceties/tweaks to the original puTTY.

www.9bis.net/kitty

Unfortunately, not many people know about this fork yet. If you are currently using puTTY, I would highly recommend kiTTY.

Comment: I use Kitty since last one tear or so. It's really nice. It's most of the missing features Putty doesnt have

Comment: How do you get tabs to work in KiTTY???

Answer (score 2):

I know you already accepted an answer, but I hate Putty and there IS another tool out there for Windows users.  A lot of people say Putty is the best - probably because it's the only tool they know about for Windows clients.  I thought it was the only option as well until I found [Poderosa](http://en.poderosa.org/).

It offers multiple panes/sessions per window, multiple tabs, simple font/color customizations, background images/colors - and probably a few more things I haven't found yet.

It's the only tool I use now for telnet/ssh/console(serial) terminal shell sessions.  It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: But there's been no activity on it since 2006.

Comment: but but.. putty *is* the best !

Comment: @Dennis: granted, but it works and the source IS available for special circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [SecureCRT](http://www.vandyke.com).

Answer (score 1):

check for [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), a terminal console for windows which allows ssh, public keys, X forwards, multi-tabs, and many linux commands in windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

[Absolute Telnet](http://www.celestialsoftware.net/) seems to offer some of what you're looking for, including tabbed connections.

Answer (score 0):

[mRemote](http://www.mremote.org/) is an Open-Source 'connection management' app.  (It has since been sold to another company, but the source is still available.)  In addition to PuTTy sessions (you need to have it installed), it'll also manage RDP v6, VNC, HTTP and so on.

Development has stopped on mRemote and moved to the new product, but it's fine at the final release, v1.50

Comment: There is a fork of it - mRemote NG. You can find it at http://www.mremoteng.org/

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up.  I had downloaded a the installers and source just-in-case

Answer (score 0):

I use the ssh client in Cygwin's port of the `OpenSSH` package all the time in Windows XP. The thing I like most about it is that it works pretty much exactly the same way as the ssh on every UNIX and Linux, in terms of capabilities, command-line options, and config files. This means you can cruise the UNIX and Linux forums for help and hints, and their suggestions will almost always apply to the Cygwin client.

Answer (score 0):

I use Console on windows which gives me the tabbed interface, and cygwin underneath, so i get ssh, bash, etc.

It's nice because you can also have a tab with cmd running, or whatever shell you need.

Console is available on sourceforge.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add +1 to those suggesting PuTTY, but in conjunction with WinSCP at the same time; that way you can have WinSCP handle the login details and jump into PuTTY at the touch of a key.

Answer (score 0):

It might also be worth mentioning [MindTerm](http://www.cryptzone.com/products/agmindterm/), an SSH client written entirely in Java. This is useful on computers with restrictions or policies about allowed programs.

The most useful (and portable) way to run MindTerm is via the Java applet, over at http://rumkin.com/tools/ssh/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cryptzone.com/products/mindterm/ Nindterm is also located here. Java based, and lots of goodies.